# Adding wiki summary to tags

Tags: support, tagging, tag-wiki-excerpts

I just messed up something when trying to edit tag wiki summary. I tried creating one for [malaria](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malaria) but since it is a synonym for [health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), I unintentionally added a summary to that tag. Even though it has to be peer reviewed, I felt obliged to share my mistake here...

BTW, how do I add/suggest a summary to synonym tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Synonym tags don't have their own tag wiki.